# Как сделать хронику/историю с данными android?

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть приложение на андроид которое работает в паре с микроконтроллером и в котором выполняются определенные действия, и есть результат этих действий, как итог работы программы. В результат входят показатели полученные с микроконтроллера, они у меня выводятся в textview а мне бы хотелось сделать что-то типа истории действий. Что это значит: человек получает показатели с микроконтроллера несколько недель подряд и нужно сделать так что-бы он мог посмотреть предыдущие результаты за прошлую неделю например, и смог увидеть динамику изменений. Для этого я так думаю что нужно будет создать какую-то бд на телефоне, в которую будут сохраняться данные с приложения для дальнейшего ознакомления, или может не бд а просто документ... Возможно я не сильно понятно объяснил свой вопрос, если что спрашивайте уточню, буду благодарен за любую помощь и советы:)

Comment: а вопрос ваш в чем? Да, БД + например, `RecyclerView` для отображения истории

Comment: вопрос в том, как это все будет работать, просто я работал с sql и java но в том случае бд уже была мною создана и все столбцы и строки были прописаны командами, а здесь в apk файл нельзя будет впихнуть бд я так понял, просто мне не сильно понятно как это все реализовать без уже существующей бд

Comment: Хорошо все будет работать) БД хранится на устройстве отдельно от приложения или apk. Ее можно создавать и использовать программно на любом этапе разработки. Посмотрите, как создавать и работать здесь: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/android-sqlite.php или здесь: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/74-urok-34-hranenie-dannyh-sqlite.html . Если у вас появится конкретный вопрос или проблема - изложите их.

Answer (score 1):

Да, все верно. Вы должны использовать БД. Лучше всего подходит по простоте и функционалу [Sugar ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/) 
После того, как сохраните данные в бд, вы можете достать их сортируя по дате.

Comment: предлагать "левые" ORM , когда google зарелизил свою ORM Room, которая к тому же заточена под Architecture Components (является их частью) как то не очень правильно наверное